# how can I get data properly?

Tags: python, api

Hi I am new to python I use python 3 on a mac. I don't know if this is relevant. Now to the question. I need for school data from an api, but I get an error.
 `<module 'requests' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>`. Can somebody explain what this means

```
import requests
requests.get('https://api.github.com')
print(requests)
```

Comment: this is not an error. It is the output of what you are printing.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the module `requests` instead of the response of your request.
Try this one:

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
print(res.content)
```

Comment: If it helped you, consider accept the answer to help other people :)